# How to make a Tooltip transparent to mouse events?

Tags: java, javafx

A `javafx.scene.Node` has the ability to make it transparent to mouse events, so that it won't be selected as target for such events:

> Node.mouseTransparentProperty()
>   If true, this node (together with all its children) is completely transparent to mouse events. When choosing target for mouse event, nodes with mouseTransparent set to true and their subtrees won't be taken into account.

Unfortunately this features is not yet implemented for `javafx.scene.control.Tooltip`.
There is an open feature [request](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8092020?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel) for that - but there doesn't seem to be a lot of activity on that topic.

My question is: Is there any workaround for this? How can I make a Tooltip mouse-transparent to route mouse events to the underlying control?

Comment: Couldn't you just add a listener for the Tool tip and just forward the event to the listener for the underlying control?

Comment: The problem is: how do I know which control exactly is currently under the tooltip? more precisely: what control is at the current mouse position (except for the tooltip)?!

Comment: not 100% but `getParent()` might tell you what container has the tooltip set?

Comment: tooltip has no `getParent()`

Comment: If you know where the tooltips are set and they are unique you could map the text (.getText()) to the parent container that way? Sorry, I'm not sure of a better way to handle this. The only other idea I have is to use the location of where it pops up and find the container underneath (which may or may not work for your setup)

Comment: @jkeuhlen I think you may be missing that `Tooltip` is implemented as an independent window, so its entire scene graph is independent of that "underneath" it. This makes your approach very difficult, at best...

Comment: @James_D Right it isn't an easy work around and if it was a simple feature to implement given the architecture, that request probably wouldn't have been open for two years. I'm kind of just spit-balling ideas to try and help OP out. I think the `getText()` values hard coded to map to their container may be the easiest solution, but it is significantly less maintainable.

Comment: I suppose that a tooltip is blocking access to some component behind it but, do you really need to make it event-transparent? Add a listener to the tooltip and, when receiving a mouse click, make it disappear, so the user can discard it whenever they want, or add a listener for a mousedragged event to let the user move the tooltip out of the way or something like that.

Comment: Hello. May I ask whether you ever found an universal solution to this problem?

Comment: @DragonGamer no, i didn't

Comment: Oh well, JFX can be quite disappointing sometimes...

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still looking for a solution. I found a hacky way in javafx-8 (using internal API!!). Its propably patched in javafx-8+, so from a maintainablility standpoint not a good option, but at least something:

```
    public static boolean correctNativeMouseEvent(MouseEvent event, Scene exclude)
    {
        Scene targetScene = getTargetScreen(event, exclude);
        if(targetScene != null)
        {
            PickResultChooser chooser = new PickResultChooser();

            targetScene.getRoot().impl_pickNode(new PickRay(event.getScreenX() - targetScene.getWindow().getX() - targetScene.getX(),
                    event.getScreenY() - targetScene.getWindow().getY() - targetScene.getY(),
                    1, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY), chooser);

            PickResult res = chooser.toPickResult();
            if(res != null)
            {
                Point2D pos = res.getIntersectedNode().localToScene(res.getIntersectedPoint().getX(), res.getIntersectedPoint().getY());

                MouseEvent newEvent = new MouseEvent(null, null, event.getEventType(), pos.getX(), pos.getY(),
                        event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY(),
                        event.getButton(), event.getClickCount(),
                        event.isShiftDown(), event.isControlDown(), event.isAltDown(), event.isMetaDown(),
                        event.isPrimaryButtonDown(), event.isMiddleButtonDown(), event.isSecondaryButtonDown(),
                        event.isSynthesized(), event.isPopupTrigger(), event.isStillSincePress(), res);

                targetScene.impl_processMouseEvent(newEvent);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    static Scene getTargetScreen(MouseEvent event, Scene exclude)
    {
        double x = event.getScreenX();
        double y = event.getScreenY();

        double sx, sy, sw, sh;

        Iterator<Window> itr = Window.impl_getWindows();

        if(itr.hasNext())
        {
            for(Window w = itr.next(); itr.hasNext(); w = itr.next())
            {
                sx = w.getX();
                sy = w.getY();
                sw = w.getWidth();
                sh = w.getHeight();

                if(sx < x && x < sx + sw
                        && sy < y && y < sy + sh
                        && w.getScene() != exclude)
                    return w.getScene();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

upon creating a tooltip you just add the following:

```
Tooltip tp = new Tooltip();
// use filter to catch before anything can be consumed
tp.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, E -> {
    // now correct the event
    correctNativeMouseEvent(E, tp.getScene());
    // although it is optionally, I would recommend to just consume the event anyways
    E.consume();
};
```