# Javafx Window order

Tags: javafx, window, z-order

Im trying to search a way to obtain the z-order of all currently showing Windows (not just Stages!) or just for a specific collection of Windows if that makes a difference.

I have tried several options including the non-public API, but I can't seem to find any native/standard way. An alternative would be to 'register' all my Windows and listen to their 'focus-property' and determine the z-order from that information. But just the fact that you need to 'register' in order to make that approuch work is a reason for me to keep looking for a generic solution.

Any help/suggestions are welcome, thanks in advance

Comment: What are you attempting to achieve with this?

Comment: it is part of a java-8 'hack', to diverse events to a underlaying Window. I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31437758/how-to-make-a-tooltip-transparent-to-mouse-events/51973252#51973252) with an example. This does work most of the time, unless there are multiple branches in the Window hierarchy (or no owner system at all). Basically the wrong Window is targeted in those edge cases. Currently I have a working alternative using the 'register' system I described, but I thought it wouldn't hurt to ask if someone has found an easy and reliable solution to this.

Comment: You must post a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: @user1803551 Not sure if you read the question and comment. Its not that I want help with fixing a broken part of coding. Moreover, I got already a working system. Its a simple question for a possible workaround for a (missing) feature. If nothing can be found, so be it. But I figured it wouldn't hurt to ask ;)

Comment: I read the question and the link you gave. Questions of this nature - asking for a solution to a problem (in contrast to an explanation of working code etc.), requires that you provide an example of a scenario in which the problem occurs. In your case, provide a runnable code example giving a certain window hierarchy and the expect z-order you want to get back. To clarify, from your point of view, you *are* trying to "fix a broken part of coding" because the code you have currently is unsatisfactory *for you*. Note that you have 3 close votes for "off-topic", so it's not just me.